# Security concerns of a slim restful api

Tags: php, rest, sql-injection, slim

I am following this slim tutorial:

https://www.shift8web.ca/blog/2015/04/use-php-to-set-up-a-restful-api-with-simple-authentication/

I just want to get data from a database for a java app. Are there any obvious security issues with the approach put forward in the tutorial? If so, how would you go about stopping sql injection and DDos attacks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Authentication

There is basically nothing wrong with the authentication approach in that tutorial many system work just as simple as that.

But if your app is running on many diffrent java clients, I would generate an access token for every device individually.

If you want a perfect implementation follow the [OAuth2](http://oauth.net/2/). But in most cases this will be an overkill. (Correct me if im wrong..)

### SQL Injection

Well in the examples of the tutorial there are no parameters given to the SQL query string so there is no SQL Injection.

If stuff is getting more complex I would absolutely not recommend to work with that suspicious `lib/mysql.php` class.

If you don't want to implement a library to work with your database go with plain [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

There you can use prepared statements to prevent SQL Injection:

```
$statement = $connection->prepare("select * from `users` where age = :age");
$statement->bindParam(':age', '42');
```

If you are of the lazy kind you can also make use of a query builder (like [Hydrahon](https://github.com/ClanCats/Hydrahon) or [Pixie](https://github.com/usmanhalalit/pixie)) which will take care of the the prepared statements itself.

```
$q->select('users')->where('age', 42)
```

### DDos attacks

In case you are really afraid of DDos attacks there are many solutions.

If you have really heavy queries you can implement a simple rate limiter with PHP itself.

You could also use a service like [Cloudflare](http://cloudflare.com/) which will automatically block attacks.

If you rely on a in house solution buy a firewall that supports a rate limit or use a [varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/) proxy for example.